# Automatically add "headers" and "produces" attributes to my @RequestMapping

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I implemented a REST API via Spring MVC. Here is an example of a mapping:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/videos", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json", produces = "application/json")
```

There are many of them, so I wonder if it's possible to *factorize* the `headers` and `produces` attributes, so that I don't have to specify them in each mapping, in order to lighten my code?

The best would be a custom annotation which automatically sets the two attributes, for example:

```java
@JsonRequestMapping(value = "/videos", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

But I haven't been able to implement such one...

Comment: Add a `@RequestMapping` to a base class containing the global attributes. Then on yuor method you only need to add `@RequestMapping("/videos")`. Depending on the version of Spring you can also use `@RestController` instead of `@Controller` that will already customize some things for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put `@RequestMapping` also on a class next to a method (see [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping)). If you want globally available attributes put a `@RequestMapping` on a class, this will be merged with the one on the method.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(headers = "Accept=application/json", produces = "application/json")
public class YourController { ... }
```

Then your method only contains the method and url.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/videos", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public Object someMethod(...) { ... }
```

You also might want to take a look at [`@RestController`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-restcontroller) as that also configures some defaults for your controller. Like not needing a `@ResponseBody` anymore on your methods.

```
@RestController
public class YourController { ... }
```